# Ajax in codeigniter for changing only div in view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

> Hello, I want to be able to change only part of the div in my view i
>   have tried to write the codes but they are not working perfectly. how
>   it works is when i click the button it suppose to sent the value to a
>   js then using js to sent data to the controller.

**SCRIPT:**

```
  function getValue(datas){
     alert(datas) ;
     var mydiv = datas;
     $.Ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:<?php echo base_url('/mama/load_view/');?>
          data:{"mydiv":mydiv},

         success:function(data){
             $('#mang_server').html(data);
         }
     });
 }
```

**PHP:**

```
  foreach($student_prof as $row){
      $gen = "GeneralInformation";
      echo '<input type="submit"  value="GeneralInformation" class="btn btn-primary active" name="general" id="submit" onclick="getValue("'.$gen.'")">';
      echo '</div>';

 }
```

> The Controller code

```
public function load_view(){

    $data1 = $this->input->post('mydiv');

    if($data1 == "GeneralInformation"){

        $this->load->view('student/profile_view');
    }
    else {
        $this->load->view('student/profile_view');
    }


}
```

Comment: In controller you are loading same page every time.

Comment: you can check for the ajax request here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590688/jquery-ajax-post-in-codeigniter and here http://runnable.com/UXczcazDrMMiAAGl/how-to-do-ajax-in-codeigniter-for-php

Comment: you are loading the same view page whatever the condition is..... and also refer ajax tutorials and you can find many resources on how to achieve your goal. You can either echo your data so that the data will be send as response to the js file which can then run the dom manipulations. Now you have done something that renders ajax usage meaningless in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery load function.

```
 function getValue(datas){


     var mydiv = datas;
     url = "<?php echo base_url('/mama/load_view');?>/" + mydiv;
     $('#mang_server').load(url);

 }
```

Controller

```
public function load_view($data1){



    if($data1 == "GeneralInformation"){

        $this->load->view('student/profile_view');
    }
    else {
        $this->load->view('student/profile_view');
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks i will give you a feedback

Comment: The problem is i also do not think if the button pass the value to the java script i need help also.

Comment: also correct button code: echo '<input type="submit"  value="GeneralInformation" class="btn btn-primary active" name="general" id="submit" onclick=\'getValue("'.$gen.'")\'>';

Comment: echo '<input type="submit"  value="GeneralInformation" class="btn btn-primary active" name="general" id="submit" onclick="getValue("'.$gen.'")">';
 Thats the problem it does not pass the value

Comment: user this code for that echo '<input type="submit" value="GeneralInformation" class="btn btn-primary active" name="general" id="submit" onclick=\'getValue("'.$gen.'")\'>';

Answer (score 0):

to load your view in `div` using `ajax` use `echo`

```
echo $this->load->view('student/profile_view', $data1, TRUE);

public function load_view(){
$data1 = $this->input->post('mydiv');
if($data1 == "GeneralInformation"){
       echo $this->load->view('student/profile_view', $data1, TRUE);
    }
    else {
       echo $this->load->view('student/profile_view', $data1, TRUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.saty will give you a feedback

Answer (score 0):

change you php code to this

```
 foreach($student_prof as $row){
      $gen = "GeneralInformation";
     $output .='<div>';
     $output .= '<input type="submit"  value="GeneralInformation" class="btn btn-primary active" name="general" id="submit" onclick="getValue("'.$gen.'")">';
      $output .= '</div>';

 }
echo $output;
```