# CodeIgniter - How to pass a value from a view to a controller?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to pass the value which I am taking from the javascript to a controller. But I don't use any function. I just want to access the value which I get from the view in the controller. I have the following view.

```
<select id="selected_year" name="selected_year" data-live-search="true" style="margin-left: 27px;" >           
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
<option value="2024">2024</option>
</select>
```

I am getting the value of the drop down using the following javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#selected_year").live('change', function() {
        var selected_year = $(this).attr("value");

       alert(selected_year);
       window.location.reload(); 

    });
</script>
```

I want to just pass the value I am getting from the above javascript into a controller. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: where exactly do you want your data go to?

Comment: jQuery `live()` has been deprecated for years.

Answer (score 1):

You would accomplish that either by sending a POST request that would be dispatched to a controller action (synchronously or asynchronously, depending on your need) or passing it as a query string in the url and then checking for it's presence in your controller.

Comment: Are you looking for Jquery Ajax Php calls. If so there are so many examples out there.  Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590688/jquery-ajax-post-in-codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your data form view to controller via three way

```
1.POST ,GET(form submitio).
2.making it in link(URi segment)
3.via Ajax
```

Comment: I don't have a controller function here. I just want to take the drop down value and send it to the controller. without having a controller function can i use Ajax?

Comment: yes way not. There is change() function for dropdown.in jqury
$('#yourdropdownid').chnage(function(){
alert('here)// to check is it work
// your ajax call here
});

Comment: I am asking something different.in ajax method we have to send the url. which means the controller method.since i don't have a controller method how can i do that?

Comment: i did,t get you.If you don't have any method then where you want the data to be send

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to submit everytime user change dropdown

```
var data = $('#selected_year').val();

     $("selected_year").on('change',function(){

     $.ajax({
        url: yourcontroller,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {

        },
    });

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a controller to provide the dynamic part of the url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#selected_year").live('change', function() {
    var selected_year = $(this).attr("value");

    // NEXT 2 LINES ARE THE SOLUTION. substitute your own controller URL on the next line.
    $url = '<?= base_url()index.php/controller/method?>/'+selected_year+'';
    window.location.reload($url); 

});
</script>
```

Here is your controller:

```
function method($year){
     echo $year;
}
```

Comment: sorry bro, first time i posted an answer here. next time i'll also provide little explaination :)