# How to pass view data to Controller by CodeIgniter using ajax Code?

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem to delet the row data from a page. After clicking "OK" buttton nothing would be appear.

```
<td><a id ="mybutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm_delete_button" data-id="<?php  echo $row -> id?>"  href="" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
```

The modal is

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm_delete_button" role="dialog" aria-labelleby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" z-index: 1050;>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delet this data</h>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <h4>Are you sure? </h4>
              <div id="done"></div>
            </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirmOk">Ok</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The JQuery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

          $('#mybutton').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $('#confirmOk').data('id',id);
              });

          $('#confirmOk').click(function(){
           var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax {
              url : "<?php echo base_url();?>item_list/delete_item/",
              type : "post" ,
              data : {"id":id},
              dataType:"json",
              success : function (data) {
                $('#confirm_delete_button').modal('hide');

                } 

                  }
                    });
              });
        </script>
```

The function of controller file item_list.php file is

```
public function delete_item () {
    //$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $this -> item_list_model -> delete_item ($id);
     echo $id;
}
```

The item_list_model.php file is

```
public function delete_item ($id) {

    return $this -> db -> query ("DELETE FROM item WHERE id='$id' ");

            }
```

The output is [The "OK" button does not delet the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd01a.jpg)

Comment: try to echo $this->input->post('id'); what is the result?

Comment: It shows noothing after clicking "OK" button

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code

**Controller**

```
    public function delete_item () {
        //$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $result = $this->item_list_model->delete_item ($id);
             if($result > 0 ){
             echo "success";
             }else{
             echo "failure";
             }
    }
```

**Model**

```
    public function delete_item ($id) {      
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete('item');
        return $this->db->affected_rows();          
        }
```

ajax

```
           success : function (data) {
            //$('#confirm_delete_button').modal('hide');
           alert(data);
            }
```

Comment: can you check `$id=$this->input->post('id'); echo $id;` check the value of id in controller

Comment: Nothing appear :(

Comment: try to alert id after `var id = $(this).data('id');`

Comment: after adding alert ID aftr #confirmOk button it shows the id of the row . 
So i think i have something error on my ajax code

Answer (score 0):

Actually your ajax post endpoint into controller should return some response using echo + json enconde. In that way your success callback into ajax jquery call can catch it and continue the flow correctly (hiding modal).

[JQuery Ajax POST in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590688/jquery-ajax-post-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

try changing `data : {"id":id},` into `data : {id:id},` maybe the data id didn't sent correctnly in the controller thats why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks mate. 
After adding alert id. It shows the correct id for the top row data. But under the top row data, the id says the "Undefined".