# Send search term and custom flag to php function via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm looking for a way to filter autocomplete results if the custom flag is sent to function, together with the search term. For example, if the user wants to find all cities that have stadium/swimming pool, etc. he can pick this as a filtering option.

```
var filter = $.inArray('1', selectedTypes);
```

This line searches only one flag to see if it's working

I have autocomplete set up and working fine without the filter, but now I'm not sure how to set it up. Any help is appreciated.

jQuery:

```
$('#city').autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var selectedTypes = $("#filter").val();
            var filter = $.inArray('1', selectedTypes);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/cities/ajaxGetCities/" + request.term,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {

                    if (typeof(data[0]) === 'undefined') {
                        return null;
                    }
                    response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                        return {
                            label: value.cityName,
                            value: value.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#city").val(ui.item.label);
            return false;
        },
        autoFocus: true
    });
```

PHP (in controller, using CodeIgniter):

```
public function ajaxGetCities(string $term, int $filter = null)
{
    if ($filter) {
        $cities = getFilteredCities($filter)
    } else {
        $cities = getCities($term);
    }

    $filteredCities = [];

    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        if (stripos($city->cityName, $term) !== false ) {
            $filteredCities[] = $city;
        }
    }

    exit(json_encode($filteredCities));
}
```

I tried this in JS, and removed func arguments in controller but the $_POST was empty

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {term: request.term, flag: filter},
    url: "/cities/ajaxGetCities",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {

    if (typeof(data[0]) === 'undefined') {
       return null;
    }
    response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
        return {
            label: value.cityName,
            value: value.id
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Which php framework are you using? I'm not that familiar with php but I think that it's the key..

Comment: CodeIgniter @MoshFeu

Comment: "the $_POST was empty"...this might be because you send the data as JSON (due to `contentType: "application/json"`)...what is the server expecting? By default PHP expects normal form data, not JSON. If you send JSON, a little bit of extra code is needed to process it. I don't know if CodeIgniter would do that for you or not. Is there any particular need to use JSON here? Try just removing that contentType line and see if it helps

Comment: Also, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17591440/863110) answer could help.

Comment: @ADyson yes, that was the fault, thank you! Can you convert your comment to answer please?

Comment: @Moirae done, thankyou. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "the $_POST was empty"

...this is because you send the data as JSON, due to specifying

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

in the AJAX options. But what is the server expecting? By default PHP expects normal form data, not JSON. If you send JSON, a little bit of extra code is needed to process it.

If you simply remove that line from your AJAX options, the data will be sent as form data (the default) and PHP should be able read it happily as standard POST variables.